# How to pause Nest.js Kafka consumer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

I am using Kafka.js in a Nest.js project. 
This is how I initialise KafkaClient:

```
@Module({
...
providers: [{
      provide: 'KAFKA_CLIENT',
      useFactory: async (configService: KafkaClientConfigService) => {

        const kafkaOptions = configService.getKafkaOptions();
        return ClientProxyFactory.create(kafkaOptions);
      },
      inject: [KafkaClientConfigService],
    },
  ]
...
})
```

Now I inject KafkaClient to my Controller, and I wish to consume messages with intervals. 
While there is a way to do it with Kafka.js using `consumer.pause()` I could not find any reference to such option in KafkaClient.

Is there any option to do so either by pausing or by throttling the consumer?

Comment: Can you please add your subscriber code here?

Comment: Have you tried asking on their Github as an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientKafka` has a `protected consumer` property. On the consumer itself you can call `pause()` and `resume()`.

To use these methods I'm currently extending the `ClientKafka` with a custom class and use it as provider instead.

```
import { ClientKafka, KafkaOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices'

export class KafkaClient extends ClientKafka {
  pause() {
    this.consumer.pause()
    // ...
  }
}
```

Make sure to use the custom class as provider in your app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: ClientKafka, useClass: KafkaClient },
  ]
})
```

Or use `useFactory` to inject dependencies too.

Comment: I am gettting an error `TypeError: this.kafkaClient.pause is not a function`.

Comment: Make sure to use the `KafkaClient` as provider. Updated my answer to reflect this.